# Angular: Where to Place akitaConfig

Tags: angular, angular-akita, akita

I've tried placing `akitaConfig` directly in the constructor of my `app.component.ts` file, which has it being called before anything else, but it doesn't seem to properly configure the data stores created afterwards. I'm trying to set `resettable` to `true` globally. The only way I'm finding to do this is by setting it on each individual store, which isn't ideal.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call it in the main.ts file before any stores get created.

Comment: Thank you! I think what was tripping my up was `this.store.resettable` wasn't returning `true`, so my check wasn't passing to reset it.